# how to call didselectrow method for inner table of uitableviewcell

Tags: ios

I am using a tableview1 inside tableviewcell, when click tableview1 of tableviewcell it appears on main tableview, when i select tableview1 cell it select main tableview why?

Answer (score 0):

Register your UItableVIewcell in didselectrow func and then Add condition in didselectrow func something like this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: bandCellId, for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell // your cellview name

    if tableView == cell.tableview1
    {
        // do something for tableview1
    }
    else
    {
        //  do something for maintableview

    }
```

hoping this might help you.